# What is the best framework for Unit Testing in JavaME?

Tags: unit-testing, java-me, frameworks

What is currently the best tool for JavaME unit testing? I´ve never really used unit testing before (shame on me!), so learning curve is important. I would appreciate some pros and cons with your answer. :)

Comment: Thanks for your comments fellas, but does anyone have actually used any of these frameworks and would like to share the experience?
Thanks ;)

Comment: There is a similar question asked with additional answers at
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114288/what-unit-test-frameworks-would-you-recommend-for-j2me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it will depend on what kind of tests are you planning to do. Will you be using continuous integration. Is running tests on handsets a must.

If tests are more logic/data processing tests, the you can do fine with JUnit. But if you need to use some classes from javax.microedition.*, then the things will become a bit tricky, but not impossible.

Some examples: a test for text wrapping on screen, that would need javax.microedition.lcdui.Font. You can't just crate a font class using jars shipped with WTK, because at initialization it will be calling some native methods, that are not available.

For these kind of tests I have created a stub implementation of J2ME. Basically these are my own interpretation of J2ME classes. I can set some preconditions there (for example every character is 5 pixels wide, etc). And it is working really great, because my test only need to know, how J2ME classes respond, not how they are internally implemented.

For networking tests I have used [MicroEmulator's](http://www.microemu.org/index.html) networking implementation, and it has also worked out well.

One more issue with unit tests - it is better to have your mobile projects as a java project using Java 4,5,6, because writing test in 1.3 is, at leas for me, a pain in the...

I belive, that starting with JUnit will be just fine, to get up and running. And if some other requirements come up (running tests on handsets), then You can explore alternatives.

Comment: Your approach looks great, could you talk more about your stub implementation of J2ME?

Answer (score 0):

I'll be honest, the only unit tester I've used in Java is [JUnit](http://www.junit.org/) and a child project for it named [DBUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/) for database testing... which I'm assuming you won't need under J2ME.

JUnit's pretty easy to use for unit testing, as long as your IDE supports it (Eclipse has support for JUnit built in).  You just mark tests with the @Test annotation (org.junit.Test I think).  You can also specify methods that should be run `@Before` or `@After` each test, as well as before or after the entire class (with `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass`).

I've never used JUnit under J2ME, though... I work with J2EE at work.

Answer (score 0):

Never found an outstanding one. You can try to read this document : 
[how to use it](https://developer.sonyericsson.com/getDocument.do?docId=87520)
and here the link to : [download it](https://developer.sonyericsson.com/site/global/newsandevents/latestnews/newsjuly06/p_mobile_juint1.0_javame_cldc.jsp)

Made by sony ericsson but work for any J2ME development.

And I would recommend you spend some time learning unit testing in plain Java before attacking unit testing on the mobile platform. This may be a to big to swallow one shoot.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There's a framework called J2MEUnit that you could give a try, but it doesn't look like it's still being actively developed:

http://j2meunit.sourceforge.net